# Problema al descargar en pdf reportes jasper

Tags: java, jasper-reports

Tengo un problema con mi proyecto java web donde tengo unos reportes creados en Jasper Report , el problema es que después de visualizar un reporte, si descargo el pdf, el sistema me muestra que solo lo puedo exportar en formato jsp, por lo tanto al querer abrir despues el pdf, este no se habre por no tener la extensión pdf. En el código java se muestra correctamente el formato "Application/pdf", pero no se descarga como pdf.

Acá dejo el código

```
                    <%
                    try{
                    Connection conn=ConexionMysqlCargomove_db.getInstance().getConnection();
                    File reportFile=new File(application.getRealPath("reportes/reporteVuelosMasUsados2/reporteVuelosMasUsados2.jasper"));
                    Map parametros=new HashMap();


                    String fechaDesde=request.getParameter("txt_fecha_desde");
                    String fechaHasta=request.getParameter("txt_fecha_hasta");

                    parametros.put("fechadesde", new String(fechaDesde));
                    parametros.put("fechahasta", new String(fechaHasta));

                    byte [] bytes= JasperRunManager.runReportToPdf(reportFile.getPath(), parametros,conn);
                    response.setContentType("application/pdf");
                    response.setContentLength(bytes.length);

                    ServletOutputStream output=response.getOutputStream();
                    response.getOutputStream();
                    output.write(bytes,0,bytes.length);
                    output.flush();
                    output.close();
                    }
                    catch(java.io.FileNotFoundException ex)
                    {
                        ex.getMessage();
                    }
                %>
```

Comment: Prueba a añadir algo así: `response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"nombre_de_tu_fichero.pdf\";");`

Comment: debo reemplazar response.setContentType("application/pdf"); por el código que indicas?

Comment: hola probé agregando esa linea mas abajo y funciona sin reemplazar la linea response.setContentType("application/pdf"); , lo único es que solo descarga el pdf de inmediato y no muestra la pantalla de visualización del pdf. Como se puede hacer para muestre la pantalla de visualizacion del pdf y adeams permita descargarlo en pdf?

Comment: hola, ya probé quitando attachment; y ahora muestra bien la visualización del pdf y al presionar descargar descarga en pdf.

Comment: muchas gracias por la ayuda